# Revenge of the Singular Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The latest episode of our saga includes at least:

- [scooter](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scooter)

Anyone gemically endowed care to fix?

(Alternatives such as tag merging and alternative tags also worth considering of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag renamed to [scooters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scooters), as it should be. We have [motorcycles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycles), so [scooters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scooters)  makes sense somewhat. Both are in somewhat similar category, but rules for driving or renting them are different, so it's better to have a separate category for them.

Comment: I think it's arguable whether a separate category is warranted especially since this is surprisingly the very first question specifically about scooters/mopeds since we started though they have been mentioned a few times.